# Why is $\sin (3x) \le 2$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I recently tried to solve this inequality:

> $$\sin(3x)≤2$$

Even though the answer is **true for all x ∈ $\mathbb R$**
I can't understand how $\sin(3x)$ can be equal to $2$ if **$-1≤\sin(x)≤1$**.

And onother question: to solve any inequality with $≤$ $≥$, is it necessary to be true for both $<$/$>$ and $=$ to be able to solve the inequality or I can solve them even only one of them is true?

Like in the previus question I belived that $\sin(3x)<2$ is true but $\sin(3x)$ can't be equal to $2$.

Comment: $\sin(3x)\le2$ means that **either $\sin(3x)<2$, or $\sin(3x)=2$**. As $\sin(3x)<2$ holds (for any real $x$), we can say that $\sin(3x)\le2$ holds.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\le$ means "less than OR equal to". Thus, $x\lt a\implies x\le a$. Furthermore, $-1\color{#C00}{\le}\sin(x)\color{#C00}{\le}1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement means

$$\sin(3x)≤2 \iff \sin(3x)<2 \quad \lor \quad \sin(3x)=2$$

and $A\lor B$ is true when at least one among $A$ and $B$ is true.

Therefore the given statement is true because $\forall x$ we have $ \sin(3x)<2$.

Answer (score 6):

Nobody is claiming that $\sin(3x)$ is sometimes equal to $2$. I suppose that you agree that you always have $-1\leqslant\sin(3x)\leqslant1$. So, since $-2<-1$ and $1<2$, you always have$$-2\leqslant\sin(3x)\leqslant2.\tag1$$In other words, the inequalities $(1)$ holds for every real number $x$.